# Number of non-decreasing functions of n boolean variables

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If f(a) is greater than or equal to f(b) for two domain elements a,b in X^n {0,1} whenever the number of 1's in a is greater than or equal to the number of 1's in b, that function is called a non-decreasing boolean function.

How many non-decreasing functions of n boolean variables exist?